# Parsing a text file using Jsoup

Tags: android, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup, android-file

I have a `Continent.txt` file placed in my res/raw folder. Inside it contains the following.

```
<div class="continents"> 
  <a href="#US">US</a> 
  <a href="#CA">Canada</a> 
  <a href="#EU">Europe</a> 
</div>
```

I am able to parse the text **US, Canada, Europe** using jsoup, but when I display them to a TextView, they show up in one line. The output looks like this.

**US Canada Europe**

I want the ouput to be like this.

**US**

**Canada**

**Europe**

This is my code.

```
package com.example.readfile;


import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txtContinent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtContinent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        ArrayList<String> arr_linkText = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Document doc;

            try {
                Resources res = getResources();
                InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.continent);

                byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
                in_s.read(b);

                doc = Jsoup.parse(new String(b));
                Element link = doc.select("a").first();
                String text = doc.body().text(); 

                arr_linkText.add(text);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                txtContinent.setText("Error: can't open file.");
            }

            return arr_linkText; // << retrun ArrayList from here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

            for (String temp_result : result) {

                txtContinent.append(temp_result + "\n");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I do not know how to read the file line by line, I hope someone can illustrate it to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the text of the entire body of the document at once.  You need to parse it out by each element, like so

```
Elements links = doc.select("a");
for (Element link : links) {
    arr_linkText.add(link.text());
}
```

in case it wasn't clear, the above code is meant to replace the following --

```
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String text = doc.body().text(); 

arr_linkText.add(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set [`android:inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) to include `textMultiLine`?

Comment: This did not do it. Later on I might be working with ListView, so even if it worked with a TextView, it would not be useful for ListView.